# Question on equating arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I have two int arrays x and y, and both of them have length 3. x={0,1,2}.

Is there any one step way to assign the values of x to y. When I do y=x, and try to print the values of y,

the code does not compile.

I dont want to go through the pain of writing a for loop, and write y[i]=x[i]

Comment: Retagging, because `regex-negation` makes no sense here.

Comment: Go through the pain.  The compiler may optimize it to something more efficient.  For small arrays, individual assignment by cell is faster than a loop; and usually faster than a call to `memcpy`.  The overhead involved in a function call or for loop is the determining factor.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `memcpy` or `memmove`:

```
memcpy(y, x, sizeof x);
```

Comment: You are correct that the loop inside `memcpy` will do the same job. This is not to suggest that the code you offer will run faster, much less that it will be safer.

Comment: On a lot of machines, `memcpy` is hugely optimized.  Now, in this case, it's only a 3 element array, so that probably doesn't matter.  Why would it not be safer?  Somebody already debugged `memcpy` - if I write my own loop, I might make a mistake...

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop.

These are essentially fixed pointers, so you can't just assign one to another. You have to copy each value.

*edit*

Here's why I don't recommend `memcpy`:

1. It's not faster for any small
   number of elements; it will likely
   be slower.
2. The version of memcpy he's using
   does not include any safeguards to
   prevent buffer overrun. It's very
   easy, even for non-novices, to
   confuse the number of elements with
   the total size of the elements,
   leading to a serious bug. It's less
   easy to mess up a for loop.
3. Since this is just C, you can
   (usually) safely memcpy an element.
   If this were C++, you would want to
   ensure that the copy constructor was
   invoked. This makes the use of
   memcpy a bad habit.

In direct response to Carl:

4. Yes, `memcpy` can be very fast for
   large arrays of simple data. This is
   not what we're dealing with here,
   though.
5. I'm not concerned about bugs *in* `memcpy`,
   but the ease of having a bug in using it.
   It requires the count of bytes, but the
   *natural* thing would be the count of elements.
   A `for` loop would use the element count.
   On many platforms, there are safer versions
   that infer the buffer size and prevent
   overwrites; I'd recommend one of those, if
   possible, when `memcpy` is a good idea.
6. If this were an array of C++ objects, such
   as `std::string`, then using `memcpy` instead
   of invoking the copy constructor would be a
   bug in itself. Yes, I do realize that the
   example is C, not C++, but that doesn't
   make it a good idea.

Comment: Well a loop *will* have to happen, but you certainly don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: You don't need to, but the compiler won't do it for you, and I would not recommend `memcpy` in this case.

Comment: Mind explaining why you don't recommend `memcpy` when it will do the job for him?

Comment: Why would `memcpy` be slower? Not explained. Point 2 is irrelevent since the size of the arrays are known to be 3 ahead of time. Point 3 is irrelevent because its C, not C++, but you pointed that out so its okay.

Comment: Regarding point #2, most people would just use `sizeof` on the array, which just does the Right Thing in this case. As for using `memcpy` to copy arrays, it's a fairly commonplace C idiom. C++ is a different language with different rules; just because something is frowned upon there doesn't mean it is equally applicable in C.

Comment: @mathepic: For an array of three ints, the fastest copy would be to hardcode the whole thing: `a[0] = b[0]; a[1] = b[1]; a[2] = c[2]`. Having said that, a for loop would still be optimized very well. In contrast, `memcpy` is optimized for larger blocks of data, so the overhead could easily exceed the entire cost of the copy.

Comment: @Pavel: You do have a point, but I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion. First, like many people, all of the C code I've written in the last decade has technically been C++. Second, copying two buffers of the exact same size is the easiest case. The more general case would involve such things as copying the middle three out of five into a buffer of three. Using STL, that's easy to do quickly and safely. Using a for loop, it's easy to do quickly and safely. Using memcpy, it's a recipe for disaster. Essentially, it's a premature optimization.

Comment: If you're using C code thats compiling under C++, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Please let me know if you feel I've left any other issues unanswered or see any errors.

Comment: @mathepic: Then I must have been doing it wrong for some time now. I recently wrote a DLL that had to plug into the OS using a C-style interface. For security reasons, I was not able to take advantage of `std::string`, so I had to do C-style string manipulations. Nonetheless, I wrote it in a CPP file so that I could use the buffer-safe versions of `memcpy` and similar functions. If that's wrong, I don't *want* to be right.

Comment: You can do it with `count`: `memcpy(y, x, count * sizeof (x[0]));` but `count = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`. Note that `sizeof` tends to become a function instead of an operator.

Comment: @levif: Adding `count` to that doesn't improve anything.

Comment: @mathepic: The requirement was for C code, the best solution was to use C-like code in C++.

Comment: Several compilers can recognize `memcpy` calls with small constant length values and replace them with simple move instructions.

Comment: @nategoose: This addresses only the issue of efficiency, and all it does is argue that `memcpy` *might not* be worse in some cases. But it's not going to be *better* for short arrays, regardless.

Comment: @levif: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Readiness for what?

Comment: @Steven Sudit: `count` in my memcpy proposal has the same role than the upper bound of the copy loop. memcpy is scalable and can be inserted inline at the compiler will (unless forbidden by user). Moreover memcpy is the most efficient with unaligned data structure. A loop is falsely safer; bugs can be introduced anywhere in code ;)

Comment: @levif: This doesn't explain what count improves readiness for, so I'm going to just disregard that statement. My point was that copying the middle few elements out of an array is trivial with a for loop but easy to get wrong with memcpy. I don't think that what you said in any way addresses this point. In fact, it appears to be unrefuted.

Comment: disagree with point #1 : memcpy is implemented as an intrinsic in many compilers, and modern compilers are smart enough to switch between multiple implementations based on the size of the memcpy - for example, gcc4 on x64-64 will unroll using direct mov's for arrays up to 128 bytes and then switch to rep movsq above that.

Comment: @matja: With all due respect, I addressed this in my reply to @nategoose, above.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can't do this:

```
int x[ 3 ] = { 0, 1, 2 };  // an array of three items
int y[ 3 ];                // another array of three items

y = x;                     // compile error - y isn't a pointer that can be reassigned.
```

You can do this:

```
int x[ 3 ] = { 0, 1, 2 };
int *y = x;   // a pointer to an array
```

You're creating `y` as a pointer to the array `x`, rather than a copy of `x`. If you change the values of `x`, those changes will also appear when referencing `y`.

Answer (score 1):

If two or more variables are declared as the same type of struct, and the definition of the struct contains arrays, the variables can be assigned to each other and the arrays will be copied in their entirety.  Sometimes it may be handy to create a struct containing a single array, for precisely that purpose.

Comment: That's true, but it's going to involve a reinterpret_cast and only works for specific sizes.

Comment: One can't assign between the array and the struct, but if one is always using a certain size of array for a certain purpose, using a "typedef" to define a struct type containing the array may be handy.  On some embedded systems this may also improve code size; e.g. on PICC-18, a struct-to-struct copy will take seven words of code space; a "memcpy" will take twelve.

Comment: Your mileage may vary, but I haven't found struct-to-struct copying to be highly optimized. If anything, it's something you generally try to avoid, in favor of const ref.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Generally from what I've seen, struct-to-struct copying is implemented using a memory-copy routine unless the structure is the same size as a primitive type.  Usually the routine accepts parameters in registers rather than the stack, though; on 8-bit embedded compilers, the size is often a byte, even though memcpy() would require a word.  As for const-ref, that's good for architectures with base-displacement addressing, and poor for architecutres which require manual multi-precision math for pointer offset computation but offer efficient direct accessing.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: On one architecture I use, for example, incrementing an unsigned char foo would take 1-2 instructions, but incrementing ptr->foo (non-zero offset) would take 6-7 instructions.  One need not use a structure very much before copying it becomes more efficient than passing and using a pointer to it.

Comment: You're quite right that many of my assumptions hold only for modern Intel processors and their equivalents. Some of that is going to have to change as ARM becomes more important.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: The PIC, which I use presently, and the ARM, which I'd like to use, require very different types of coding to achieve optimal results.  The PIC, for example, can access direct locations faster than it can access locations at pointer offsets.  On the ARM, the normal accessing mode is +/-4095 bytes relative to a pointer register.  Accessing an arbitrary location (with nothing useful in registers) would take 2-3 instructions (4-5 cycles), while accessing a field in a struct whose address is in a register would take one (3 cycles).

Comment: Yes, the ARM has some nice features. The one I like best is the ability to handle conditionals by skipping over an operation, as opposed to performing an arbitrary jump. Just think of what that does for the ternary operator!

Comment: @Steven: In one hobby project I'm doing in hand-tweaked ARM code, I figure most instructions are doing at least double-duty (combining shift with other logic) and a few are doing triple duty.  I would not expect a compiler to yield anything near as tight, but when trying to emulate a 1.19Mhz memory system in hard real time (i.e. miss a beat and the host CPU will fetch erroneous data and likely crash) there's not much leeway inefficient code.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not looking at hand-tweaking. At most, I expect to use the tried and true method of compiling, looking at the output, and adjusting appropriately. The sad part is that, with .NET or JVM, you can't really do that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Roll them up in a struct (or union, in this case).

```
struct int3 {
    int A[3];
};

int3 x = {{ 0, 1, 2 }};
int3 y = x;
```

This will not generally result in better code from the compiler than doing individual copies of each element or using `memcpy`, and may result in worse code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop or to call a library function that does that for you, e.g. memcpy/memmove.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way built into the language.  You can probably find a library call to do it, though.  If it's something you're doing frequently, you could easily write the function yourself.